# (Cocoa) Monitoring File Changes with the File System Events API

Tags: cocoa, nsfilemanager, fsevents

I have a task which needs to be notified when a image is copied to a folder. I found a example from: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/FileSystemEvents/_index.html

It works when using command:

```
    $ cp motorcycle.png motorcycle-copy1.png
```

It doesn't work when I copy a image in and paste, or I drag a new image in the folder.
The fsevents_callback reacts, it menas the folder is changed. but how do I know there is a new image copied to the folder or a image changed in the folder?